# Generating lexicographic next key to use in the azure table query string

Tags: javascript, azure, winjs, azure-table-storage

Azure table query api does not natively have startswith operator support but it can be built by using query string of the format below. Example below is trying to do rowKey.startWith('myrowkey') operation.

```
?$filter=PartitionKey eq 'mykey' and RowKey ge 'myrowkey' and RowKey lt 'myrowkez'
```

For this, I am writing a function `getNextKey` which return lexicographic next key. This function is used to generate the query string.

```
   {
        _getStartWithQueryString: function getStartWithQueryString(partitionKey, rowKey)
        {
            var nextRowKey = this._getNextKey(rowKey);
            var filterValue = "PartitionKey eq '" + partitionKey + 
              "' and RowKey ge '" + rowKey + "' and RowKey lt '" + nextRowKey + "'";
            var parameters = {
                '$filter' : filterValue,
            };
            var params = Utils.Http.stringifyParameters(parameters);
            return params;
        },
        _getNextKey: function getNextKey(key)
        {
            var lastCharCode = key.charCodeAt(key.length - 1);
            var nextLastCharCode = ++lastCharCode;
            var result = key.substr(0, key.length - 1) + String.fromCharCode(nextLastCharCode);
            return result;
        },
        queryAzureTable: function queryAzureTable(...)
        {
            var baseUrl = config.storageAccount.url;
            var queryUrl = this._getStartWithQueryString('2013-05-28T07', '2511cc20-ecff-46d2-bc13-ec9cb9ca3498');
            var resourceUri = 'mytable()' ;
            var url = baseUrl + resourceUri + '?' + queryUrl;

            // more code to invoke azure table query entities rest api
        }
```

now the question:
RowKey can contain alphanumeric characters, '-' and '.'

My test results show like this:
getNextKey('myrowkey') -> 'myrowkez'

getNextKey('00') -> '01'

getNextKey('09') -> '0:'

getNextKey('0-') -> '0.'

Do you see any correctness issue with the `getNextKey()` which may lead to wrong results for the azure query?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to do this and work perfect for me:

```
public static string NextComparisonString(this string s)   
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        throw new ArgumentException("The string argument must not be null or empty!");

    var lastChar = s[s.Length - 1];
    if (lastChar + 1 > char.MaxValue)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot convert the string.");

    return string.Format("{0}{1}", s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1), (char)(lastChar + 1));
}
```